# How to share a profile page I created to Facebook that's dynamically created using php

Tags: php, dynamic, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

How can I share a profile page I created to Facebook when the page is dynamically loaded based on a id?

here is the head tags with the generated id -

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.my_site.com/page.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="Profile Name" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="https://www.my_site.com/path/image.jpg" />
```

Heres the FB SDK -

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and finally the button itself -

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.my_site.com/page.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&gt;" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.my_site.com%2Fpage.php%3Fid%3D%253C%253Fphp%2Becho%2B%2524id%253B%253F%253E&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

When I run it, it just shows the main website page my_site.com not the profile page.

Comment: `&lt;?php echo $id;?&gt;` - you don’t expect that to work now do you?

Comment: Care to elaborate, are you referring to the &lt;?php not being <?php or the passing of variables in the url in general?

Comment: The first of course.

Comment: Thanks yes I'm aware, FB formatted that I have tried it with the correct syntax but no luck

Comment: And have you checked what the FB debug tool has to say yet?